# Excel formula giving incorrect result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a relatively simple Excel formula, adding two cells (264+0=264), subtracting a sum of a number of other cells (sub-result 0) and finally subtracting a third cell (176). The expected result is 88, the formula returns 0. All cells are general & numeric.
See in the attached screenshots the formula in its context as well as the last 4 evaluation steps. What dumbfounds me is the last one, where Excel flat out says that 264-176 is 0.

[image: Formula]

[image: Evaluation -3]

[image: Evaluation -2]

[image: Evaluation -1]

[image: Evaluation finished]

Comment: What, exactly, is your formula? From your screencaps, I see the first two cells are substracted, but you say they are added

Comment: I think the screenshot shows that: Hrs_Accr+Hrs_Abs-SUM(...)-Hrs_Trgt, or Column N + Column O - SUM(...) - Column M

Comment: I'm looking at the fist Evaluate with only shows substractions. In any case, it's usually better to include formulas and code as text. It would also be useful to get a minimal reproducible example with sample data

Comment: Please **edit your question** to provide sufficient information **as text** which can be copy/pasted, so that someone can reproduce your problem. Certainly `264-176` does not equal zero, either in the real world or in Excel. Speculation as to what is causing your formula evaluation to display that, in the absence of being able to reproduce the problem is less likely to lead to a solution than merely providing information that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you provide the data source picture or sample?

Comment: It was aliens. Just to be sure, I tried restarting (actually multiple times) yesterday, but did not help. Today it works even though I have not touched it since. Probably yesterday was the day that 264-176 equaled 0 in Excel...

Comment: Since it is not a reproducible problem, consider deleting it as it is unlikely to be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the formula =264-SUM(K3:K10)-176 in cell K3, you will get exactly this result. This happens if the cell refers to itself.